# Отображение старой страницы до полной загрузки новой

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день!
Имеется страничка с php-скриптами, довольно увесистая. Она обновляется через определенный промежуток времени. При обновлении показывается 2/3 страницы, а остальная часть подгружается через длительное время. Я попробовал использовать событие `onLoad` и `visibility:hidden`, но теперь страница на долгое время просто пропадает, а нужно, чтобы картинка не терялась, и в это время отображалась еще не обновленная информация, до полной загрузки страницы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать на `html`, `php`, `javascript` или `jquery`?
Спасибо.

Comment: на всякий случай изучите она грузится долго, или отрисовывается в браузере. Если у вас только `body` страницы меняется то можете страницу не обновлять, а аяксом получать контент и заменять `$("body").html(..)`. А если целиком вообще заменить, то вам [сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11984907/1216425)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Решил вопрос с помощью jquery: не обновляя страницы через определенный промежуток времени меняется контент. Правда, время обновления контента увеличилось примерно в 1,5 раза.